# MP Media Player track length display (xcode)

Tags: objective-c, audio, duration, mpmediaitem

I have the `curentPlaybackTime` set to my progress bar but how do I set the `MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration` so the bar updates?

There is an answer here that explains it but I dont fully understand it so I would appreciate a full description or an example of how its done?

Answer (score 0):

UIProgressView progress property expects an value between 0.0 and 1.0. So to update the progress bar you need to divide the track length through the current playback time.

```
MPMediaItem *myTrack = ...; 
MPMusicPlayerController *myPlayer = ...; 
UIProgressView *myProgressView = ...;

myProgressView.progress = [myTrack valueForKey:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] / myPlayer.currentPlaybackTime;
```

Comment: miho thank you for answering and im sure ur right but if u can send me like both the .h and .m files to my email because im still not doing something right or at least post them here just like i asked in full because i need to know what im doing wrong

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not going to code a whole application for you. The lines above should contain all information required to work with.